# Highlight words from string started with @

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting

There is a string that may contain nicknames given by `@nickname`. Nickname can be inputed by user with typo by concatenation with previous word, like

```
Hello my inst is@nickname
```

Also nickname word can be situated at the beginning of the new paragraph, hence just using `split(' ')` wouldn’t work.

What I want ultimately do is to after user inputs, highlight nicknames in string by covering them with `<span>` setting some styles and adding onclick link to instagram with that account.

Comment: I think you have to clarify this more, would you like to have a live highlighting while typing in the input or when you finished writing the input. Should be the highlighting inside the input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I’ve made so far:

```
<script>

window.onload=function()
{
var text = "Hello @buf world @text";
text = Synt(text);

var a = addP(document.body,text,30,30,"black",20);
a.innerHTML=text;
}

function Synt(a)
{

if(a.search('@')==-1)
return a;
else
{

var regex = /@/gi, result, indices = [];
while ( (result = regex.exec(a)) ) {
    indices.push(result.index);
}

var a1 = (' ' + a).slice(1);
var ar = a.split('');

for(var i=0;i<indices.length;i++)
{
var r=[];
var rr=0;

for(var j=indices[i];j<a.length&&(isLetter(a[j])||a[j]=='.'||a[j]=='_'||rr==0);rr++,j++)
r[rr]=a[j];

r=r.join('');

a1 = a1.replace(r,'<span style="color:blue">'+r+'</span>');
}

return a1;
}
}





function isLetter(str) {
  return str.length === 1 && str.match(/[a-z|0-9]/i);
}

function addP(par,text,left,top,color='black',size='17px', fun=0)
{
var p = document.createElement('p');

p.style.position = 'absolute';
p.style.color=color
p.style.fontSize=size;
p.style.fontFamily='Arial';
par.appendChild(p);

p.style.left=left;
p.style.top=top;

p.innerText=text;

if(fun)
p.onclick=fun;

return p;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Don’t know why another answer was deleted, I really wanted to mark it as correct 